# I am getting java.lang.SecurityException while get user name in android?

Tags: android

I am getting the below exception, I already added all permissions in the manifest file.

> java.lang.SecurityException: You need MANAGE_USERS, CREATE_USERS,
> QUERY_USERS, or  GET_ACCOUNTS_PRIVILEGED permissions to: get user name

find below code:

```
context=this;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
    final UserManager userMgr = (UserManager) context.getSystemService(context.USER_SERVICE);
    if (null != userMgr) {
        try {
            textUserName.setText(userMgr.getUserName());
            Log.d("UserName",userMgr.getUserName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(ex.getMessage().toString(),"");
        }
    }
```

Please help to find out the current user name. Please help to find out the current user name.
Thank You!

Comment: The message looks pretty clear *You need MANAGE_USERS, CREATE_USERS, QUERY_USERS, or GET_ACCOUNTS_PRIVILEGED permissions to: get user name*

Comment: @Jens In question only, I added [I already added all permissions in the manifest file], please read the question before marking negative

Comment: maybe you need to ask user for granting this permission? check out [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting), placing some perms in manifest isn't sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `getUserName()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/UserManager?hl=en#getusername):

> This call is only available to applications on the system image.

In other words, that API is for device manufacturers. Your app cannot hold any of the necessary permissions to use that API.